# Stop .toFixed from rounding the number

Tags: javascript

I Have the following

```
var dividedResult =  (893/ 200);    

var result = dividedResult.toFixed(decimalPlaces);
```

The divided result is

```
4.465
```

and the result is

```
4.5
```

How do I stop the rounding in this case?

I want the result to be

```
4.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Prasath's answer, if you wanted to distinguish between rounding up and rounding down to 1 decimal place you would do

Rounding down (4.4)

```
result = Math.floor(result * 10)/10;
```

Rounding up (4.5)

```
result = Math.ceil(result * 10)/10;
```

For your case, for any number of decimal places, use

```
result = Math.floor(result * Math.pow(10,decimalPlaces))/Math.pow(10,decimalPlaces);
```

Comment: Thanks. The decimal places could be any number though

Answer (score 4):

Try this 4.465 * 10 = 44.65 .. parseInt(44.65) = 44/10 = 4.4

```
result = parseInt(result * 10)/10;
```

For any number of decimal places

```
result = parseInt(result * Math.pow(10,NumberOfDecimalPlaces))/(Math.pow(10,NumberOfDecimalPlaces));
```

Comment: Thanks. The decimal places could be any number though